# NSDate comparison fails

Tags: ios, nsdate

Here is the code, that brought me some problems:

```
    NSDate * d1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:444555883.659000];
    NSTimeInterval since1970 = [d1 timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSDate * d2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:since1970];

    NSLog(@"%@\n%@", d1, d2);
    NSLog(@"%d", [d1 compare: d2] == NSOrderedSame);
```

The problem I can't understand is that the test fails with following logs:

```
2015-02-02 07:44:43 +0000
2015-02-02 07:44:43 +0000

0 // test failed
```

What can be the reason of test fails?

Comment: Try using `XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy`

Comment: @Maarten1909 im going to use my code outside of tests. How to solve comparison fails then?

Comment: Just a regular comparison between two NSDates?

Comment: You are, in effect, comparing two floating-point numbers.  There are more bits in there than you can see, and manipulating the values the way you do is apt to twiddle some of the low-order bits.  You need to compare with a "delta", the same as you would regular floating-point.

Comment: @HotLicks pls check the update. I log 30 decimal fractions. How can I tell if there are different floating point numbers then?

Comment: Could you come up with a more complicated way to sort NSDates? compare: compares dates just fine.

Comment: @gnasher729 sorry but the question is not "how to sort dates"

Comment: @purrrminator - When they compare not equal they are different.  (No one knows what the internal format of NSDate is -- certainly not a `long`.  There are bits in there that can likely be set "randomly", and there's no guarantee that going to time interval and back gives you EXACTLY the same date.)

Comment: You need to compare using a delta.

Comment: @HotLicks pls check the updated code. I've got closer to the problem. It happens after converting to `since1970`

Comment: You need to compare using a delta.

Comment: @HotLicks maybe If you post an answer and show how to do this, we would both get what we want from each other :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing double's, so you can't simply check for equality. The fact that both instances print out the same output doesn't mean anything because the precision of the default output format is 1 second.

Compare them by doing something like this:

```
if (fabs(t1 - t2) < delta)
```

where delta is very small amount such as 0.005

Or you can set the higher precision components of the date you don't need to 0 using `NSDateComponents` before comparing them

Answer (score 1):

`if (interval1 + delta > interval2 && interval1 - delta < interval2)`

(You can do it directly with NSDates by adding/subtracting delta on the dates, but it's messier and I'm too lazy to write it out.)